# Почему не выводится таблица из базы данных полностью?

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

Создал таблицу в excel и импортировал ее в access. Далее создал Windows Form, вставил dataGridView. Стал подключать базу данных (заранее сохраненную), но у меня почему то выводится не вся таблица.[image: Получается вот так]

[image: А надо вот так]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string CmdText = "SELECT * From [Домашняя бухгалтерия]";
        public string ConnString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            " Data Source = C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\HomeTest\\HomeTest\\Домашняя Бухгалтерия.mdb";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
           OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(CmdText, 
                ConnString);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "[Домашняя_Бухгалтерия]");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Перенесите весь ваш код из конструктора в `Form_Load`, в конструкторе оставьте только `InitializeComponent()`. Проверьте, изменилось что или нет, затем исправьте код в вопросе. Код в конструкторе, изменяющий контролы, непредсказуем.

Comment: Перенес код. Ничего не изменилось. делал все как было написано на сайте https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2015/12/22/002-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-microsoft-access-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be/

Comment: Но что то пошло не так. а что именно не знаю. может не надо создавать базу данных в exel потом переводить в access?

Comment: Что выводится и чего не хватает?

Comment: выводится пустая строка в windows form. а надо чтобы полностью вставилась таблица из базы данных в access

Comment: @Никита добавтьте теги `oledb` и `winforms` к вопросу. Простите, что сразу не сказал, я просто отредактировал ваш вопрос, а вы не приняли правку, и отредактировали сами.

Comment: я не понял что за правка была))) поэтому отклонил) извиняюсь) но так получается я не правильно отредактировал?

Comment: Может не правильно подключил базу данных или она у меня каким то образом оказывается пустой?

Comment: А зачем вы создаете `OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter` и `DataSet ds`, если вы в дизайнере их уже создали. Вам всего то нужно воспользоваться созданными `tableTableAdapter.Fill(база_данных1DataSet.ВашеНазваниеТаблицы);`

Comment: В Access у вас открыта БД, которая лежит по адресу Desktop, А в программе вы открываете другую БД по адресу source/repos... Возможно, она пустая.

Comment: Спасибо всем большое. все получилось. надо было просто запустить программу. и код для отображения не нужен был совсем